# How can I refactor this Dictionary to a Class?

Tags: c#, refactoring

I feel this Dictionary is holding too much information: It holds information to build an
e-mail path and it holds extra parameters to get other data needed for e-mail templates. Here is a simplified version of my sample program:

```
void Main()
{
    //Sample Path = Root/Action/TemplateX.txt
    //Date used in other method
    Dictionary<string,object> emailDict = new Dictionary<string,object>
    {
        {"Root","Email"},
        {"Action", "Update"},
        {"TemplateName", "TemplateX.txt"},
        {"Date", DateTime.Now},

    };

    //Create email object
    Email email = new Email();


    //Send e-mail with email dictionary
    email.SendEmail(emailDict);

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Email
{

    public void SendEmail(Dictionary<string,object> emailDict)
    {
        //Build path from emailDict and use parameters from emailDict
        //Send E-mail
    }

}
```

Are there other re-factors I should consider?

Answer (score 3):

You are certainly right - what you have needs to be refactored. Perhaps reading up on standard Object Orientated principals would help. I would have something more like this, though I would need to know more of how you plan to use it (public setters may be desirable):

```
enum EmailAction { Update } // add any other possible actions

public class Email
{
    public string Email { get; private set; }
    public EmailAction  EmailAction { get; private set; }
    public string TemlateName { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; private set; }

    public Email(string email, EmailAction action, string templateName, DateTime dateTime)
    {
        this.Email = email;
        this.EmailAction = action;
        this.TemlateName = templateName;
        this.DateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public void Send()
    {
        //Build path from properties on this instance of Email
    }

}
```

Then you can simply go:

```
Email newEmail = new Email("Email", EmailAction.Update, "TemplateX.txt", DateTime.Now);

newEmail.Send();
```

Comment: I thought about this before, but what happens if what if I need to pass a ton of parameters to Email. Would you still consider the same approach, but maybe storing the parameters in another class and then passing the class to the Email object?

Comment: If there are many more params I would have a default constructor, i.e. no params, and make the property setters public then you can create your new email and set the properties you want before calling send.

Answer (score 2):

That is definitely abusing a `Dictionary`. You're losing all type safety having your value be an `object` which leaves you open to `InvalidCast` exceptions and a whole bunch of other issues. Just pull out all of your values into properties in a class:

```
public class EmailFields
{
    public string Root {get;set;}
    public string Action {get;set;}
    public string TemplateName {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}

    public EmailHelper
    {
        Date = DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Your `SendEmail` method would then take an `EmailFields` object as a parameter.

From this point, I'd also probably make `enum`'s for `Action` and `TemplateName`.

```
public enum Action
{
    Update,
}
public enum Template
{
    TemplateX,
}
```

And your properties would then be

```
public Action EmailAction {get;set;}
public Template TemplateName {get;set;}
```

Comment: Good idea, one thing is that the Templates are strings and I can't make a enum with strings, so would a class with consts be fine to such as:  `const TEMPLATE_X = "templateX.txt";`?